# Names for various color indices in QCD

Tags: terminology, group-representations, quantum-chromodynamics

In Quantum Chromodynamics with $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ there are at least two types of color indices:

1. Indices $a$, $b$, … that index the eight generators of the group $\mathrm{SU}(3)$. In some sense they index the gluons.
2. Indices $i$, $j$, … that index the three dimensions of the fundamental (or rather defining?) representation in three dimensions. Those correspond to the three colors (red, green, blue).

Example expressions are the structure constants $f^{abc}$ and the fundamental generators $(t^a)^i{}_j$ and spinors $\psi_i$. The different indices nicely show the ranges of the indices and what they act on.

From what I head in my lectures both are called „color indices“ which I find a bit unfortunate as they are two different types of indices as they go over different ranges. I would find „color index“ appropriate for the indices from 1 to 3 and „gluon index“ or „gauge index“ appropriate for the indices from 1 to 8.

Alternatively the names “color fundamental index” for $i$ and “color adjoined index” for $a$ would also convey the difference, I think.

Are there any official differentiating names for the two types of indices?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): They are both called _color_ indices because they both correspond to representations of the _color_ group.

Comment: Sure, they are linked to $\mathrm{SU}(3)_\text{color}$. As there are two different kinds of indices, one for the basis of the algebra and one for the basis of the representation, I feel the need to differentiate between the two just as they have different letters for the indices. When one says „color index $a$“ and „color index $i$“ it is implicitly understood that they mean algebra and representation. There must be words for that, aren't there?